# alias gcc='gcc -fpermissive' or modifying ./configure script

Tags: linux, compile, make, gcc, g++

I am compiling quite big project from source. The compilation always ends with:
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

I have already compiled this project one year ago. So I know a solution to this. Actualy I found more solutions:

1. Adding a typecast to appropriate line of cpp code
   (It went to endless number of changes in each file. So I found next solution.)
2. Modifying a makefile to compile that file with -fpermissive option.
   (I had to modify a lot of lines in each makefile. So I find even better solution.)
3. "g++" or "gcc" was stored in a variable so I added -fpermissive to these variables.

This is the best solution I have. It is sufficient to add this option to each makefile once.
Unfortunately this software has big number of subdirectories. So I need to modify more than 100 makefiles. It took me whole day one year ago.

Is there a way how to do this faster.

What about this?
alias gcc='gcc -fpermissive'
I am not familiar with aliases. But it should be easy to try this. Is the syntax correct? And is this one correct? alias g++='g++ -fpermissive' ? And do I need to export the alias somehow? Will the make program respect the alias?

Should I maybe change ./configure script? Or the ./configure.in? Or other file?

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are most easily set up by placing the relevant line in your `~/.bashrc` file. When you issue a command, BASH will search your `$PATH` for the first instance of an executable of that name. Aliases in your `~/.bashrc` file will always be found first so if you have an alias with the same name as an actual command (e.g. `gcc`) the alias will be executed.

So, in your case, add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` (yes the syntax is correct):

```
alias gcc='gcc -fpermissive'
alias g++='g++ -fpermissive'
```

Alternatively, you can make different aliases so that you can choose whether or not you want the `-fpermissive` flag:

```
alias gcc_per='gcc -fpermissive'
alias g++_per='g++ -fpermissive'
```

That way, you can use `gcc` to run `/usr/bin/gcc` or `gcc_per` to run `/usr/bin/gcc -fpermissive` according to your needs. Obviously, you can set the alias to whatever you want, the name is up to you.

Once you have added the relevant lines to your `~/.bashrc`, either source it (`source ~/.bashrc`) or just open a new terminal and you new aliases are set up and ready to go.

Comment: From what I can tell, `make` will not respect the alias, though.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, I know, but for future reference:

Aliasing `gcc` and `g++` in the `.bashrc` will not working within `make`. You can however overwrite `make`'s variables `CC` and `CXX` from within the `.bashrc`:

```
export CC="gcc -fpermissive"
export CXX="g++ -fpermissive"
```

That of course requires you to use `$(CC)` and `$(CXX)` in explicit rules in your makefile, but you should do that anyway. They are used in the implicit rules by default.